# Partial derivative with respect to a matrix in RNN backpropagation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, neural-networks, backpropagation

I have an issue with the following problem.
I am trying to derive the gradients with respect to $x_t, h_{t-1}, W_x, W_h$.
$x_t$ is a $N*D$ vector.
$h_t$ is a $N*H$ vector.
$W_h$ is a $H*H$ matrix.
$W_x$ is a $D*H$ matrix.

The function is $h_t=tanh(h_{t-1}W_h+x_tW_x+b)=tanh(O_t)$

I am struggling with the derivative with respect to $W_h, W_x$
The answer said that the derivative with respect to $W_h$ is $h_{t-1}^T⋅dh_t⋅(1-h_t⋅h_t)$.

$dh_t$ means the derivative obtained in the previous step.
Also, $dh_t⋅(1-h_t⋅h_t)$ is just inner product in my guess. $h_{t-1}^T⋅dh_t$ is done by matrix multiplication.
The most confusing part is how $h_{t-1}^T$ moves to the first term when the chain rule is applied.

I will appreciate if anyone could answer this question.

Comment: What is a matrix RNN?

Comment: @PC1 sorry for the confusion. This problem is the backpropagation in the RNN. I am just struggling how to apply the chain rule for the matrix. They told me that dL/dW=xT∗dL/dy,dL/dx=dL/dy∗WT
 for the equation L=f(y),y=xW
. I am wondering how to derive them.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\l{\lambda}  \def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$First, let's give each variable a **distinct** name and remove those distracting subscripts (and denote row vectors by $v^T$ rather than $v$)
$$\eqalign{
x &= x_t^T,\quad &h=h_t^T,\quad &y = h_{t-1}^T,\quad &p = O_t^T \\
q &= b^T,\quad &R = W_h^T,\quad &S = W_x^T \\
}$$
Second, given a scalar function and its derivative
$\LR{f(z),\:f'=\grad fz}$ the differential is defined as
$$df = f'\,dz$$
These functions can be applied elementwise to a vector argument (like $p$) resulting in
$$h = f(p),\quad h'=f'(p),\qquad\qquad\quad dh = h'\odot dp$$
where $\odot$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product.

Such products can be replaced by diagonal matrices
$$H = \Diag{h},\quad H' = \Diag{h'},\qquad dh = H'\,dp$$

Fortunately, the derivative of  `tanh()` is quite well known
$$dh = \LR{\o-h\odot h}\odot dp
 \;=\; \CLR{I-H^2}dp \;\equiv\; \c{M}\,dp$$
We're almost done, we just need to calculate $dp$ and substitute
$$\eqalign{
p &= q + Ry + Sx \\
dp &= \LR{R\:dy+dR\:y} + \LR{S\:dx+dS\:x} \\
dh &= M\LR{R\:dy+dR\:y} + M\LR{S\:dx+dS\:x} \\
 &= {MR\:dy+M\:dR\:y} + {MS\:dx+M\:dS\:x} \\
}$$
The vector gradients are easily identified from this expression
$$\eqalign{
\grad hy &= MR,\qquad \grad hx = MS \\
}$$
The gradients with respect to the matrix variables are trickier,
but they are
$$\eqalign{
\grad hR &= M\star y,\qquad \grad hS &= M\star x \\
}$$
where $\star$ denotes a dyadic/tensor product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\grad hS = M\star x \qiq \grad{h_i}{S_{jk}} = M_{ij}\,x_k \\
}$$
Such quantities are third-order **tensors** and are a PITA to work with using standard matrix-vector notation.

Comment: Do you know of any good references where this dyadic / tensor product, and other related ways of multiplying tensors, are defined and discussed?

Comment: Any good _Continuum Mechanics_ textbook will cover these products. Except for the Hadamard product, which has few applications in the physical sciences.

Comment: [Here's one](https://pkel015.connect.amazon.auckland.ac.nz/SolidMechanicsBooks/Part_III/index.html) such textbook.

Comment: Many thanks for your insightful answer!

Answer (score 0):

Denote
$$
\mathbf{h}_t = 
\tanh
\left( \mathbf{W}_h \mathbf{h}_{t-1} + \mathbf{W}_x \mathbf{x}_t + \mathbf{b} \right) = 
\tanh
\left( \mathbf{o}_t \right)
$$

Using same notations as in Greg's answer
\begin{eqnarray*}
d\phi
&=& 
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{h}_t}
:
d\mathbf{h}_t \\
&=& 
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{h}_t}
:
\left( \mathbf{1}-\mathbf{h}_t\odot \mathbf{h}_t \right)
\odot 
d\mathbf{o}_t \\
&=&
\left( \mathbf{1}-\mathbf{h}_t\odot \mathbf{h}_t \right)
\odot 
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{h}_t}
:
\left( d\mathbf{W}_h \right)\mathbf{h}_{t-1} \\
&=&
\left[
\left( \mathbf{1}-\mathbf{h}_t\odot \mathbf{h}_t \right)
\odot 
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{h}_t}
\right]
\mathbf{h}_{t-1}^T
:
d\mathbf{W}_h 
\end{eqnarray*}
The matrix gradient is given by the LHS of the Frobenius inner product.

Comment: Your notations are confusing. What is $\phi$? greg has not used $\phi$.

Comment: $\phi$ is the objective function you are trying to minimize.